# Querying dataframe based on numerical similarities between rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
     Allotment     Date          NDVI_Kurtosis    NDVI_Skewness
1    D             19840621      1.02             3.06
2    D             19850619      1.76             2.56
3    A             19840621      3.66             3.50
4    A             19850619      1.56             3.20
```

and I want to return every `Allotment` and associated `Date` if BOTH the `NDVI_Kurtosis` and `NDVI_Skewness` are within 1.00 of each other between the different rows.  So in this case, I would want this returned:

```
 Allotment         Date          NDVI_Kurtosis    NDVI_Skewness
    D             19840621       1.02             3.06
    D             19850619       1.76             2.56
    A             19850619       1.56             3.20
```

I have played around with using `iloc` for this but have been unsuccessful so far.

Comment: `if BOTH the NDVI_Kurtosis and NDVI_Skewness are within 1.00 of each other between the different rows` Could you explain better?

Comment: So in my example rows 1, 2 and 4 all have a kurtosis and skewness within 1.00 of each other.  Row 3 doesn't meet the requirement because the kurtosis value is more than 1.00 away from the kurtosis value in any other row, even though the skewness value is within it. Its kinda hard to explain, but I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shift function for create new columns and after you can compare them to the initial columns.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_clipboard()
df['NDVI_Kurtosis_lag']=df['NDVI_Kurtosis'].shift(1).fillna(df['NDVI_Kurtosis'])
df['NDVI_Skewness_lag']=df['NDVI_Skewness'].shift(1).fillna(df['NDVI_Skewness'])
df
df2=df[(df['NDVI_Kurtosis']-df['NDVI_Kurtosis_lag']<1) & (df['NDVI_Skewness']-df['NDVI_Skewness_lag']<1)]
df2
```

Cordialy,
Laurent.